# Storing JavaPairRDD<String, Map<String, List<String>> into multiple files

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark

I'm using Spark 1.6 and trying to solve below problem.
I have a 
    `JavaPairRDD<String, Map<String, List<String>>`. 
I would like to store this as multiple output files based on the Key of JavaPairRDD being the outer directory and Map's key being the file name.

For example if the JavaPairRDD has the below data

```
<"A", <{"A1",["a1","b1","c1"]}, {"A2",["a2","b2","c2"]}>>
<"B", <{"B1",["bb1","bb2","bb3"]}>
```

then the output folders should be as follows

```
/output/A/A1 (content of A1 should have [a1,b1,c1])
/output/A/A2 (content of A2 should have [a2,b2,c2])
/output/B/B1 (content of B1 should have [bb1,bb2,bb3])
```

I have the below code but I'm not sure on how I can change the MultipleTextOutputFormat to iterate through the value Map.

```
public static void main(String a[]) {
            JavaPairRDD<String, Map<String, List<String>> pair;
            pair.saveAsHadoopFile(directory + "/output", String.class, Map.class,
                            RDDMultipleTextOutputFormat.class);
        }



public static class RDDMultipleTextOutputFormat<A, B> extends   MultipleTextOutputFormat<A, B> {
        @Override
        protected String generateFileNameForKeyValue(A key, B value, String name) {
            return key.toString(); // + "/" + name;
        }

        @Override
        protected B generateActualValue(A key, B value) {
            //return value;
            Map<String, List<String>> map = (HashMap<String, List<String>>)value;
            for(Map.Entry<String, List<String>>entry: map.entrySet()) {
                generateFileNameForKeyValue((A)(key.toString() + "/" + entry.getKey()), (B)(entry.getValue().toString()), entry.getKey());

            }

            //return value.saveAsHadoopFile((Map)value., String.class, Map.class,
            //  RDDMultipleTextOutputFormat.class);
       }

       @Override
           protected A generateActualKey(A key, B value) {
               return null;
           }

       /*@Override
           public RecordWriter<A, B> getRecordWriter(FileSystem fs, JobConf job, String name, Progressable prog) throws IOException {
               if (name.startsWith("apple")) {
                   return new TextOutputFormat<A, B>().getRecordWriter(fs, job, name, prog);
               } else if (name.startsWith("banana")) {
                   return new TextOutputFormat<A, B>().getRecordWriter(fs, job, name, prog);
               }
               return super.getRecordWriter(fs, job, name, prog);
           }*/
      }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Akhila.